# add 2 python files to lambda_zip in terraform

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I create a lambda function using Terraform. To zip the python file, I use this:

```
data "archive_file" "get_incoming_lambda_zip" {
  type             = "zip"
  source_file      = "${path.module}/src/lbd_get_incoming.py"
  output_file_mode = "0666"
  output_path      = "${path.module}/bin/lbd_get_incoming.zip"
}
```

Previously, I was using a function defined within the `lbd_get_incoming.py` file. However, now I have moved the function to `common/utils.py`.

In order to be able to use `from common.utils import lyfunction` in my lambda function, I need to export the `common.utils` (`"${path.module}/src/common/utils.py"`) file along with the `lbd_get_incoming.py` file in the zipped version.

What's the correct syntax to achieve this? If I

Comment: Please don't keep asking the same question, especially when an existing question that you asked has an answer plus links to the basic docs that clearly explain how to use this feature of Terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`source_dir`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file#source_dir) instead of `source_file` to point to a directory where both files are stored (and in proper directory structure against each other).

If your two files come from different places, you need to put them next to each other first and then point Terraform's `archive_file` to them.

Comment: My source file is here ```"${path.module}/src/lbd_get_incoming.py"``` and utils file is here: ```"${path.module}/src/common/utils.py"```. If I change source_file to ```source_dir```, then what do I write as the path: ```${path.module}/src```? Then how will I specify where the original lambda code file/function is (```lbd_get_incoming.py```file)

Comment: The ZIP only needs to include all the files. What is the entry point to your function you specify for `aws_lambda_function`.

Comment: `${path.module}/src` as the `source_dir` makes sense to me.